# Hadoop streaming to python using mongo-hadoop

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, cloudera

I'm trying to get map-reduce functionality with python using mongo-hadoop. Hadoop is working, hadoop streaming is working with python and the mongo-hadoop adaptor is working. However, the mongo-hadoop streaming examples with python aren't working. When trying to run the example in streaming/examples/treasury I get the following error:

> $user@host: ~/git/mongo-hadoop/streaming$ hadoop jar target/mongo-hadoop-streaming-assembly-1.0.1.jar -mapper examples/treasury/mapper.py -reducer examples/treasury/reducer.py -inputformat com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoInputFormat -outputformat com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoOutputFormat -inputURI mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_hadoop.yield_historical.in -outputURI mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_hadoop.yield_historical.streaming.out

```
13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.MongoStreamJob: Running

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.MongoStreamJob: Init

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.MongoStreamJob: Process Args

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Setup Options'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: PreProcess Args

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Parse Options

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: '-mapper'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: 'examples/treasury/mapper.py'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: '-reducer'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: 'examples/treasury/reducer.py'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: '-inputformat'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: 'com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoInputFormat'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: '-outputformat'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: 'com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoOutputFormat'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: '-inputURI'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_hadoop.yield_historical.in'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: '-outputURI'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Arg: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo_hadoop.yield_historical.streaming.out'

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Add InputSpecs

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Setup output_

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.StreamJobPatch: Post Process Args

13/04/09 11:54:34 INFO streaming.MongoStreamJob: Args processed.

13/04/09 11:54:36 INFO io.MongoIdentifierResolver: Resolving: bson

13/04/09 11:54:36 INFO io.MongoIdentifierResolver: Resolving: bson

13/04/09 11:54:36 INFO io.MongoIdentifierResolver: Resolving: bson

13/04/09 11:54:36 INFO io.MongoIdentifierResolver: Resolving: bson

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/filecache/DistributedCache**
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamJob.setJobConf(StreamJob.java:959)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.streaming.MongoStreamJob.run(MongoStreamJob.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.streaming.MongoStreamJob.main(MongoStreamJob.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.DistributedCache
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 10 more
```

If anyone could shed some light it would be a big help.

Full info:

As far as I can tell I needed to get the following four things to work:

1. Install and test hadoop
2. Install and test hadoop streaming with python
3. Install and test mongo-hadoop
4. Install and test mongo-hadoop streaming with python

So the short of it is I've got everything working up to the fourth step. Using (https://github.com/danielpoe/cloudera) i've got cloudera 4 installed

1. Using chef recipe cloudera 4 has been installed and is up and running and tested
2. Using michael nolls blog tutorials, tested hadoop streaming with python successfully
3. Using the docs at mongodb.org was able to run both treasury and ufo examples (build cdh4 in build.sbt)
4. Have downloaded 1.5 hours worth of twitter data using the readme for the twitter example in streaming/examples and also tried the treasury example.

Comment: Solved:
To get it working we needed to install cloudera 4.
Then install the mongo-hadoop adapter using version cdh4
Then create the mongo-hadoop-streaming drive using version cdh3
At this point, rather than follow the instructions and install pymongo-hadoop from the repository, the best solution
`sudo pip install pymongo_hadoop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got the latest pymongo_hadoop connector installed?  What versions of the other software are you running?

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for your answer. It was the pymongo_hadoop connector that was the problem. We'd solved it a little before you gave us the hint.